# Python Pandas pull list of rows where blank in one column

Tags: python, pandas, filter, nan

I am working with a larger dataframe df.

The first column of the df is Customer_ID. It is then followed by about 50 columns.

When I pivot this dataframe I get something like this:

```
pv1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Customer_ID","Category"],values=["Sales"],aggfunc=np.sum)

pv1.head()

Customer ID | Category | Sales
123           A           345345
              B           6736
345           A           982764
```

It seems that there are blanks in the Customer ID column (see row 2).

I tried to pull a list of those rows, with this statement:

```
df.loc[df['Customer_ID'] == ' ']
```

But I get no results.

Comment: It's not a blank, there are in multi-index format, try `pv1.reset_index()`

Comment: What @JohnGalt says is correct. For second row the `Customer_ID` would be the same as first row.

Comment: oh wow - @JohnGalt; do you mind posting pv1.reset_index() as an answer, so I can upvote it? This really helped me

Comment: smile, trivial to a pro = monumental to a noob

Comment: love it already, wish it would love me back; anyway, this answer did really help me and I assume it will help other noobs as well; so I leave it up to you; if you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it and upvote it; thank you

Comment: thank you @Cedric as well; clarified it further for me